# How to open gzip file on gae cloud?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gzip, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am using python 2.7 and Google Compute Cloud. I want to process a gzip file uploaded to the gcs datastore. On Python, this would be:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('myfile.gz', 'r') as f:
    f.read()
```

Since this does is not allowed on GCS, the only option I found on [Google Cloud Storage Client Library Functions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions), is:

```
import cloudstorage
cloudstorage.open('myfile.gz', 'r'):
    f.read()
```

which does not open gzip files. Any tips on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the alternate gzip.GzipFile() access via a file object, using the file object provided by the GCS client lib:

```
import cloudstorage
import gzip

with cloudstorage.open('myfile.gz', 'r') as f:
    content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f).read()
```