# Google cloud storage create zip file with all files from a bucket folder with app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to create a zip file with all files present inside a bucket folder and write this zip file back to google cloud storage.
I want to do this with app engine standard environment but i didn't find a good example for doing this.

Comment: Hi user2494876 and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment i'm looking for the feasibility, because app engine don't have the possibility to write to a local disk, i don't know if it's possible to download all the files before creating the zip

Comment: Not with App engine, what i did was -

Create a Cloud Function, that is triggered on new file creation in the bucket

That function, fetches AND create a zip using packages like [jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip), then add this zip to storage

Note- If you want to generate each time you want, just change the trigger to HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the writable temporary file normally needed during the `zip` file creation could fit in the available memory of your instance class you may be able to use the `StringIO` facility and avoid writing to the filesystem. See for an example [How to zip or tar a static folder without writing anything to the filesystem in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885764/how-to-zip-or-tar-a-static-folder-without-writing-anything-to-the-filesystem-in/38888667#38888667)

It may also be possible to directly write the `zip` file to GCS, basically using the GAE app as a pipeline, which *might* circumvent the available instance memory limitation mentioned above, but you'd have to try it out, I don't have an actual example. The tricks to watch for would be the picking the right file handlers arguments and maybe buffering options. An example of directly accessing a GCS file (only you'd want to write to it instead of reading from it) would be [How to open gzip file on gae cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708725/how-to-open-gzip-file-on-gae-cloud/35709022#35709022)