# How to restore Tensorflow model from Google bucket without writing to filesystem?

Tags: google-app-engine, tensorflow

I have a 2gb Tensorflow model that I'd like to add to a Flask project I have on App Engine but I can't seem to find any documentation stating what I'm trying to do is possible.

Since App Engine doesn't allow writing to the file system, I'm storing my model's files in a Google Bucket and attempting to restore the model from there. These are the files there:

- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta
- checkpoint

Working locally, I can just use

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    logger.info("Importing model into TF")
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, model.ckpt)
```

Where the model is loaded into memory using Flask's `@before_first_request`.

Once it's on App Engine, I assumed I could to this:

```
blob = bucket.get_blob('blob_name')
filename = os.path.join(model_dir, blob.name)
blob.download_to_filename(filename)
```

Then do the same restore. But App Engine won't allow it.

Is there a way to stream these files into Tensorflow's restore functions so the files don't have to be written to the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tips from Dan Cornilescu and digging into it I found that Tensorflow builds the `MetaGraphDef` with a function called `ParseFromString`, so here's what I ended up doing:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from tensorflow import MetaGraphDef

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(Config.MODEL_BUCKET)
blob = bucket.get_blob('model.ckpt.meta')
model_graph = blob.download_as_string()

mgd = MetaGraphDef()
mgd.ParseFromString(model_graph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(mgd)
```

Comment: I don't see how `saver.restore(sess, model.ckpt)` is catered for in this answer. The metaGraph is restored but how are the weights transferred?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't actually use Tensorflow, the answer is based on docs and GAE-related knowledge.

In general using GCS objects as files in GAE to avoid the lack of a writable filesystem access relies on one of 2 alternate approaches instead of just passing **a filename** to be directly read/written (which can't be done with GCS objects) by your app code (and/or any 3rd party utility/library it may be using):

- using an already open **file-like handler** for reading/writing the data from/to GCS. Which your app would obtain from using either of:

  - the `open` call from a GCS client library instead of the generic one typically used for a regular filesystem. See, for example [Write a CSV to store in Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524581/write-a-csv-to-store-in-google-cloud-storage/39525052#39525052) or [pickling python objects to google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778621/pickling-python-objects-to-google-cloud-storage/37778921#37778921)
  - some in-memory faking of a file, using something like `StringIO`, see [How to zip or tar a static folder without writing anything to the filesystem in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885764/how-to-zip-or-tar-a-static-folder-without-writing-anything-to-the-filesystem-in/38888667#38888667). The in-memory fake file also gives easy access to the raw data in case it needs to be persisted in GCS, see below.
- directly using or producing just the respective **raw data** which your app would be entirely responsible for actually reading from/writing to GCS (again using a GCS client library's `open` calls), see [How to open gzip file on gae cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708725/how-to-open-gzip-file-on-gae-cloud/35709022#35709022)

In your particular case it seems the [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) call supports passing a `MetaGraphDef` protocol buffer (i.e. raw data) instead of the filename from which it should be loaded:

> Args:
>
> - `meta_graph_or_file`: `MetaGraphDef` protocol buffer or filename (including the path) containing a `MetaGraphDef`.

So restoring models from GCS *should* be possible, something along these lines:

```
import cloudstorage

with cloudstorage.open('gcs_path_to_meta_graph_file', 'r') as fd:
    meta_graph = fd.read()

# and later:

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph)
```

However from the quick doc scan saving/checkpointing the modes back to GCS may be tricky, [`save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder#save) seem to want to want to write the data to disk itself. But I didn't dig too deep.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.6 and it seems cloudstorage might only be for Python 2.7. Up to this point I've been using [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html) to get bucket contents. I don't see a way to open the file like you can with your example.

Comment: If you export the meta graphs **as text** you could try loading them like `meta_graph = blob.download_as_string()`. And assuming you'd find a way to get the raw `meta_graph` (as text) to be saved, you could save it with `blob.upload_from_string(meta_graph)`.