# google ml-engine cloud storage as a file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I am working in Python with Google Cloud ML-Engine.  The documentation I have found indicates that data storage should be done with Buckets and Blobs

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/working-with-cloud-storage

However, much of my code, and the libraries it calls works with files.  Can I somehow treat Google Storage as a file system in my ml-engine code?

I want my code to read like

```
with open(<something>) as f:
   for line in f:
      dosomething(line)
```

Note that in ml-engine one does not create and configure VM instances.  So I can not mount my own shared filesystem with Filestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to have Cloud Storage appear as a filesystem is to [mount a bucket as a file system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets#mount_bucket):

> You can use the [Google Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) tool to mount a Cloud
>   Storage bucket to your Compute Engine instance. The mounted bucket
>   behaves similarly to a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs) even though Cloud Storage
>   buckets are object storage.

But you cannot do that if you can't create and configure VMs.

> Note that in ml-engine one does not create and configure VM instances.

That's not entirely true. I see ML Engine supports [building custom containers](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/versioning#to_build_a_custom_container_beta), which is typically how one can install and configure OS-level dependencies. But only for the training area, so if your needs are in that area it may be worth a try.

I assume you already checked that the library doesn't support access through an already open file-like handler (if not then maybe of interest would be [How to restore Tensorflow model from Google bucket without writing to filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125515/how-to-restore-tensorflow-model-from-google-bucket-without-writing-to-filesystem/53132622#53132622))

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I already tried something like open("gs://bucketname/foo.bar") and the package google.cloud.storage does not seem to have an open() method.  I am surprised because I would expect a normal file-like interface to persistent storage.  I feel I myst be missing it

Comment: You can use TensorFlow FileIO library to open GCS files. Please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799117/google-cloud-ml-and-gcs-bucket-issues

Comment: @user1902291 being an actual filesystem file (on which python's default `open()` works) and having a file-like handler obtained through some call other than python's `open()` are two different things...

Answer (score 2):

For those that come after, here is the answer

[Google Cloud ML and GCS Bucket issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799117/google-cloud-ml-and-gcs-bucket-issues)

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
```

Here is an example

```
with file_io.FileIO("gc://bucket_name/foobar.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("FOO")
    f.flush()
    print("Write foobar.txt")

with file_io.FileIO("gc://bucket_name/foobar.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print("Read foobar.txt: "+line)
```