# Deploying Django to Google cloud platform

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project which is a django backend application , the application at some point  relies on  the file system to read and write videos and also load tensorflow models. 
Is  it possible to  use google app engine to  run my django app or do I  need to rent a VM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to run your Django App on App Engine.

You cannot write to App Engine file system but you can read files from your own project.

A possible solution would be to use Cloud Storage to read and write videos and load tesorflow models.

[Reading and Writing to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)

[How to restore Tensorflow model from Google bucket without writing to filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125515/how-to-restore-tensorflow-model-from-google-bucket-without-writing-to-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Django on App Engine, see https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine for more details.

There are other options as well for running Django on Google Cloud, see https://cloud.google.com/python/django/ for a complete list.